# How to broadcast to all components from root Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I want to `$emit` some data to all child components in `vue.js 2` and this is my code :

**Root Component**

```
const app = new Vue({
    created: function(){
        // here is some promise and after it done the below line runs
        this.$emit('foo', 'bar');
    }
});
```

**Child Component**

```
<template></template>
<script>
    export default {
        created: function() {
            this.$on('foo', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    }
<script>
```

It's not working.

Is there any way to broadcast some data to all child components from root?

Answer (score 1):

Vuejs is bottom up approach, means child component is compiled first and ask for `this.$on` so broadcasting will not work here with `$emit`-`$on`

Use `props` in child component to watch root data changes, giving this example where `child1` and `child2` having same root component data named `name`

```js
var child1 = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Child Component1 : Niklesh : {{name}} <div v-if='loading'>Loading...</div></div>",
    props: ['name','loading']
});
var child2 = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Child Component1 : Rishi : {{name}} <div v-if='loading'>Loading...</div></div>",
    props: ['name','loading']
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
        name: "...",
        loading: true
    },
    mounted() {
      var vm =  this;
      setTimeout(function() {
         vm.name = "Raut";
          vm.loading = false;
    }, 1000);
    },
    components: {
        child1,
        child2
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <child1 :name="name" :loading="loading"></child1>
    <child2 :name="name" :loading="loading"></child2>
</div>
```

Comment: I updated question.Please attention that have some promise before `$emit`

Comment: @SaeedVaziry : I given the solution for the same.

Comment: I am getting undefined on child component

Comment: @SaeedVaziry : check my answer its working, may be you missed something,  did you define variable inside root component `data` ?

Comment: Yes i have some variables in data at root component. also i have `vueRouter` in root component

Comment: @SaeedVaziry : share your try in your question, how it look like  ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157189/discussion-between-saeed-vaziry-and-user2486).

Comment: I uploaded a screenshot of my root instance

Answer (score 0):

Use another Vue instance as an Event bus

[Code Pen Sample](https://codepen.io/sarngru/pen/BwENpo)

```
<div id="app">
  <child></child>
</div>

var bus = new Vue()

Vue.component('child', {
  data() {
    return {
      message: 'waiting for event...'
    }
  },
  template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>',
  created: function() {
    bus.$on('foo', data => {
      this.message = data;
    })
  }
})

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  created: function() {
    setTimeout(()=> {
      bus.$emit('foo', 'bar')
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

Comment: here `1000` works if child component run its execution within 1 second if takes more than this this will not work