# Vue: remove a component when other is completely loaded

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, loading

```
<template>
    <div id="app">
      <Loading></Loading>
      <Content></Content>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Loading from './Loading.vue'
import Content from './Content.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Loading,
    Content
  }
}
</script>
```

What is the best and elegant way to handle a loading component and remove it (or vue component or change styles) when all page is loaded?

I tried with v-cloack, but I think its not working beyond data stuff.
I tried with mounted, but doesn't seems to work.

Comment: [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46863806/2815635) to display loading

Comment: @C2486 its easy if its only one child component, but it doesn't look scalabale, right?

Comment: Please share a live demo , of your example ?

Comment: Its not to big, but almost impossible to share it here. Basically, I'm using Vue-Router and child components with child components (no Vuex). The question is more aboute generic way to get it.

Comment: Please use as I did, let me give one short example.

Comment: I given an example to use component as `loading component` you use similar code to share us live demo, with expected logic.

Answer (score 2):

[`v-cloak`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-cloak) is to hide un-compiled mustache bindings until the Vue instance is ready. So you can use `v-if` to show/hide loading component.

```js
var child1 = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>Loading...</div>"
});
var child2 = Vue.extend({
    template: "<div>After Component loaded</div>",
});
var app = new Vue({
    el: "#vue-instance",
    data: {
        loading: true
    },
    mounted() {
            var vm =  this;
            setTimeout(function() {
          vm.loading = false;
                }, 1000);
    },
    components: {
        child1,
        child2
    },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.1/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue-instance">
    <child1 :name="name" v-if="loading"></child1>
    <child2 :name="name" v-if="!loading"></child2>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm confused with v-cloack. Its only for data compiled? How to do it for all render template (including images)?

Comment: `v-cloak` is for hiding html with `{{}}` tag until it is not replaced after Vue compilation.

Comment: Also please add any high HD images with any demo and other data for which you need loading.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-cloak